# I have got a 'pure virtual method called' message when i test the new <thread> feature of c++11 using the g++4.7.0, under 32bit-ubuntu-12.04

Tags: multithreading, c++11, ubuntu-12.04, gcc4, virtual-functions

### //test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
void call()
{
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    thread t(call);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
g++-4.7 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -pthread
```

The above compiled perfectly, but when I run ./test. I just get an error message that says "pure virtual method called , terminate called without an active exception"

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: No repro with g++ 4.7.1.

Comment: I have this problem on clang3.1! I thought it was a problem with that compiler, but apparently it has to do with something on libstdc++. I just switched back to gcc though, couldn't solve it.

Comment: Works fine with g++ 4.7.0 too.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error with this code is to remove `t.join()`. I know in some real-world code, I had to add a check to `std::thread::joinable()` before I called `std::thread::join()`. Might want to give that a shot.

Answer (score 4):

It is a known bug. see  http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12730.

Nobody tried to fix it, sadly.

Comment: The bug report you linked to suggests defining the following macros:
`__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1`, `__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2`, `__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4`, and `__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_8`. It worked for me.